Representations over reals
I know that the regular representation over complex field contains all its non-isomorphic irreducible representations with multiplicity isomorphic to its dimension. Is the result still true if we work with real representations? I specifically want to know the following:

Are there finitely many non-isomorphic real representations of any finite group?
Is every representation still completely reducible into irreducible representations? (I know Maschke says nothing about field being algebraically closed but I am seeing conflicting results over different resources)
Does the real regular representation contain all the irreducible real representations with multiplicity equal to the dimension of the representation?


We show regular representation over complex numbers with $\mathbb{C}G$ and over real numbers with $\mathbb{R}G$.
Let's show irreducible representations (irreps) over complex numbers with $W_i$ for $1 \le i \le m$ and irreps over real numbers with $V_i$ for $1 \le i \le m'$.
Here, $$\mathbb{C}G\cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^mW_i^{n_i},$$ where $n_i=\dim(W_i)$, but
$$\mathbb{R}G\cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^{m'}V_i^{n_i},$$ where $n_i$ is either $n_i=\dim(V_i)$, $n_i=\dim(V_i)/2$, or $n_i=\dim(V_i)/4$.
So, you see all irreps appear in the real case but not with the same multiplicity as their dimension.
We have three different types of real irreps: real-type, complex-type, quaternion-type. $n_i=\dim(V_i)$ in real-type irreps, $n_i=\dim(V_i)/2$ in complex-type irreps, and $n_i=\dim(V_i)/4$ in quternion-type irreps.
Consider $V \otimes \mathbb{C}$ to be the complexification of $V$ or, equivalently, extending the underlying field of $V$ to complex numbers. If $V_i$ is real-type, then there exists $W_i$ such that $V_i \otimes \mathbb{C}=W_i$. If $V_i$ is complex-type, then $V_i \otimes \mathbb{C}=W_i\oplus W_i^*$, where both $W_i$ and $W_i^*$ are non-isomprphic irreps over complex numbers. And if $V_i$ is quaternion-type,  $V_i \otimes \mathbb{C}=W_i\oplus W_i$, where $W_i$ is irreps over complex numbers. This construction should show you, yes there are finitely many real irreps for any finite group.
Every representation of a finite group over fields with characteristic zero are completely irreducible, and $\mathbb{R}$ has characteristic zero.
